# Detail section in row of `ng-repeat`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am creating rows using `ng-repeat`and each row has expandable section in which details are shown. i fetch data on row click and populate detail area by two way binding. but here is the problem, all details sections are bidden to common scope variables.

Can someone guide me how to tackle this problem?

One solution in my mind is to maintain `map` structure for every detail. But do not know will it be a good idea or there is any better solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Angular.js version : 1.0.8

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are binding the "ng-open" of your details tag to a boolean in the parent scope of your ng-repeat, instead of binding it to an attribute of the ng-repeat iteration itself (each loop of ng-repeat creates a child scope of your actual scope).
Here is an example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <td ng-click="showContent = !showContent">
      <details id="details" ng-open="showContent">
        <summary><em>Details</em></summary>
          <p ng-bind="thing.info"></p>
     </details>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On each loop of your repeat, it will create a child scope, and each of those scopes will contain a "private" showContent attribute that your ng-open directive will be attached to.

Hope this is your problem and this helps you.

--Edit--

(Of course that you have to be sure that the "showContent" attribute isn't declared on your scope controller)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry i forgot to mention angular version. in our project its 1.0.8 and i am afraid this directive is not in that version